# passing/dereferencing sObject types as variables

Tags: apex

I have a utility method that includes something like...

```
 public void methodName (id passedID) {
    ...
    Contact result = [SELECT id, name From Contact WHERE id = :passedID]; 
    ... }
```

Since the method's function is generic I'd like to make a single query that works for any class/sObject.  The goal being something like the following:

```
    passedID.sObjectType result = [SELECT id, name From passedID.sObjectType 
                                       WHERE id = :passedID];
```

I keep coming back to getSobjectType() but can't find a means of dereferencing the result so that I can use it as an sObject reference in the method.

What's the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `Database.query` and return a generic `SObject` and cast it from your endpoint, for example:

```
public SObject getRecord(Id passedId)
{
    String sObjectType = String.valueOf(passedId.getSObjectType());
    String queryFormat = 'SELECT Name FROM {0} WHERE Id = {1}';
    String soql = String.format(queryFormat, new List<String> {
        sObjectType, '\'' + passedId + '\'';
    });
    return Database.query(soql);

    /*
    I can't remember if you can return a single record this way.
    You may need to alternatively implement:
    List<SObject> candidates = Database.query(soql);
    return candidates.isEmpty() ? null : candidates[0];
    */
}

public void someOtherMethod()
{
    Contact methodResult = (Contact)getRecord(someContactId);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I used a similar type of logic, except with field sets to determine which field(s) should be queried per object type. And yes, you can return a single SObject record from a Database.query or inline SOQL, assuming there is exactly one row returned. Remember that if no rows are returned (e.g. through sharing changes, perhaps), this can cause an exception.